# Rspec mongoid - Testing embedded document callback (after_save)

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongoid

I'm trying to create a test to check if my post's embedded document(author) call to it callback method.

Code:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated
  {....}
  # relations
  embeds_one :author, cascade_callbacks: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
  {...}
end

Class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  {...}
   embedded_in :post
   after_save    :my_callback_method

   def save_estimation_logs
     {...}
   end
  {...}
end
```

test:

```
RSpec.describe Author, :type => :model do
  context "Create author on Post" do
    let!(:post) { create(:post, :with_external_author) }
    it "should call after_save method my_callback_method when saving" do
      expect(post.author).to receive(:my_callback_method)
      expect(post.save).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

when i'm trying to run this rspec - i got

```
Failure/Error: expect(post.author).to receive(:my_callback_method)

   (#<Author _id: 5c7ea762f325709edac2ae84, created_at: 2019-03-05 16:44:18 UTC, updated_at: 2019-03-05 16:44:18 UTC>). my_callback_method(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Can you guys help me understand how should I test this embedded document callbacks?

Comment: What is the exact error.

Comment: You're trying to test Rails and/or Mongoid code. My advice is to not do this. Just rely on the fact that the Rails and Mongoid teams wrote sufficient tests and trust those tests.

Comment: Zeitnot - the exact error in the post.

Comment: aridlehoover - i want to make sure the callback after_save exists in the model (making sure no one will delete it by mistake and so on..)

Comment: Then test the outcome of the `after_save`.

Comment: I got your point, but for my tests, I need to check that I call to after_save method (no matter what the results are)

Comment: If any of the answers helped you please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should trust `mongoid` to call `after_save` and test `my_callback_method` in isolation.

Now, as said in the comments, that you want to check if someone deleted the `after_save`, you can add a test for:

```
RSpec.describe Author, :type => :model do
  context "Author" do
    it "should define my_callback_method for after_save" do
      result = Author._save_callbacks.select { |cb| cb.kind.eql?(:after) }.collect(&:filter).include?(:my_callback_method)
      expect(result).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct but there is a number of outstanding issues in Mongoid related to callbacks in persistence. Ensure the callback is called in normal operation (i.e. when you save a post from a Rails console).

Comment: I checked - it happened, the callback called, but i want to put it in some test - but for some reason, I'm not find any idea how to do it.

Comment: Did you perform the same exact operations, i.e., created a post with author (which saves both), then invoked `save` on the already saved post (which wouldn't make any meaningful database changes)?